# C# Regex for XML-Sequence in between square Brackets

Tags: c#, regex, xml, xslt

I'm having quite a struggle with finding a proper RegEx for this.
I need to Match a RegEx in a String like this:

```
//XML-Syntax before
<![CDATA[
//a lot of XSL-Syntax between including '[' and ']' chars
]]>
//XML-Syntax after
```

Now I need to get just the XSL-Syntax between which I just can't get to work. Especially the square brackets which are inside as well as limiting the string are giving me a hard time.
Does somebody know a elegant solution for this?

Best regards

Comment: If the input is XML and you want to read out the contents of a CDATA section, why don't you use an XML API like LINQ to XML or `XmlDocument`?

Comment: Thank you @MartinHonnen I was not aware that CDATA might be a common section. Can you give an example on how to extract everything of CDATA using XmlDocument class?

Comment: @Access, I have posted an answer with a snippet of C#. Note that in most cases there is no need to distinguish a normal text contents from a CDATA section so I have first shown how to simply read out the text contents of an XML element node with `InnerText`. But if you need to access a CDATA section separately then you can do that as shown and read out is `Value` (or I think `InnerText` as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CDATA section is syntactic sugar in XML to avoid the need of escaping embedded markup. If you have an element and you need its string content, whether it is in a normal text node or in a CDATA section node, you can simply access the `InnerText` of the element in the DOM implementation (`System.Xml.XmlDocument`) of the .NET framework. If you really need to address the CDATA section itself then you can access it as child node of an element node and read out its `Value` property. So the following snippet of C#

```
    string xml = @"<root><data><![CDATA[<xsl:stylesheet xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'><xsl:template match='/'><test/></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>]]></data></root>";
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentElement["data"].InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentElement["data"].FirstChild.Value);
```

outputs

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'><xsl:template match='/'><test/></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'><xsl:template match='/'><test/></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could then parse that string again as XML with XmlDocument if you need to select any data in the XSLT code.